# Merge multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

I have several tables like this:

```
Table A                               Table B
Col Aa    Col Ba     Col Ca         Col Ab   Col Bb   Col Cb   Col Db
  1        Ab1         Ac1            1        Bb1      Bc1      Bd1
  2        Ab2         Ac2            3        Bb3      Bc3      Bd3
  4        Ab4         Ac4            3        Bb3'     Bc3'     Bd3'
```

And I would like to have a resulting table like that

```
Col X       Col Y         Col Z
  1          Ab1           Ac1
  2          Ab2           Ac2
  4          Ab4           Ac4
  1          Bb1           Bd1
  3          Bb3           Bd3'
  3          Bb3'          Bd3'
```

It's basically adding all the rows of multiple tables, but manually deciding what columns in each table should be added, and deciding what column from table A goes with what column of table B, and in what column of the final table (and what columns not to add)

I guess I could just do copy paste but I would prefer not to. I could also change the name columns in each table if necessary. `Col Ba = Col Y`, `Col Ca = Col Z`,  `Col Db = Col Z`and so on, but again I would prefer not to.

I'm using Excel 2016. Using relationships doesn't work because apparently, data has to be unique in each column (no duplicates)

Comment: But col X has duplicates and you need a condition or key or relation between tables to know what and how to merge

Comment: It cannot be done then? I guess I could create a dummy column in each table as an ID for the relationship.

Comment: You need a common column between your Tables and at least one condition in order to create a formula to copy the other information

Comment: Let's say I do have a column table. How do I do it?

Comment: You can use Vlookup or Index/Match you have to precise it in order to write the formula, you have to explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for Merge Data Ranges when has the same structure.

```vb
Sub MergeData()

Dim i As Integer
Dim xTCount As Variant
Dim xWs As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next LInput:
xTCount = Application.InputBox( "The number of title rows" , "", "1" )

If TypeName(xTCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
If Not IsNumeric(xTCount) Then
MsgBox "Only can enter number" 
GoTo LInput
End If
Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
xWs.Name = "Merge Data"

Worksheets(2).Range( "A1" ).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range( "A1" )

For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(i).Range( "A1" ).CurrentRegion.Offset( CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but although I am familiar with C I don't fully understand what the code is doing. I guess I would need to understandt it to adapt it to my tables.